# Group Concat in Django

Tags: django, orm, django-views, group-concat

I am having a model

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    project = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null= True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
```

THis is my query for fetching the data

```py
qs = Project.objects.values('project').annotate(
    total_hours=Sum((F('end_time') - F('start_time'))), start_date =F('start_date'),).distinct()

    for i in qs:
         print(i)
```

Now what I am getting is

```
{'project': '1', 'total_hours': Decimal('2.0000'), 'start_date': datetime.date(2020, 8, 1)}
{'project': '3', 'total_hours': Decimal('1.0000'), 'start_date': datetime.date(2020, 8, 1)}
{'project': '1', 'total_hours': Decimal('1.0000'), 'start_date': datetime.date(2020, 8, 2)}
```

Here if project 1 coming twise in to diffrent dates.... How to elimintate second one add as a single object

So I am trying to use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)

This is the code

```
class GROUP_CONCAT(Func):
    function = 'GROUP_CONCAT'
    template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s)'
    output_field = DateField()
```

But I am not sure How can I use it with Django ORM Query

Comment: what happens if you remove distinct from the end of qs?

Comment: I try to remove duplicate element ..... Even if I am not passing distinct it will return the same query set